# Why can i not use %s instead of %c?

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

The whole function the question is about is about giving a two dimensional array initialized with {0} as output and making a user able to move a 1 over the field with

```
char wasd;
scanf("%c", &wasd);
```

(the function to move by changing the value of the variable wasd is not important i think)
now my question is why using

```
scanf("%s", &wasd);
```

does only work partly(sometimes the 1 keeps being at a field and appears a 2nd time at the new place though it actually should be deleted)
and

```
scanf("%.1s", &wasd);
```

leads to the field being printed out without stop until closing the execution program. I came up with using %.1s after researching the difference between %c and %s here [Why does C's printf format string have both %c and %s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846024/why-does-cs-printf-format-string-have-both-c-and-s)? If one *can* figure out the answer by reading through that, i am not clever or far enough with c learning to get it. 
I also found this [fscanf() in C - difference between %s and %c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356070/fscanf-in-c-difference-between-s-and-c) but i do not know anything about EOF which one answer says is the cause of the problem so i would prefer getting an answer without it.
Thank you for an answer

Comment: Have you ever checked the documentation of `scanf` ? None of your code snippets can work. Partially or fully.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: Ah. Let me correct myself. First one can work. Not clear what is "partially" here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it does..i am asking why two things do not work

Comment: Try `scanf("%1s",&wasd);` . It Worked for me in **GCC**

Comment: @anoopknr After some [humble pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humble_pie)  due to my comment. `scanf("%1s",&wasd);` fails as that saves 2 characters, the 1 read and a _null character_.

Comment: @anoopknr adding to chux' comment, "*It Worked for me*" doesn't have much value with C. **undefined behavior** might do whatever, including, just by chance, what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as that, `%s` is the conversion for a (non-empty) string. A **string** in C always ends with a `0` byte, so any non-empty string needs at least **two** bytes. If you pass a pointer to a single `char` variable, `scanf()` will just overwrite whatever is in memory after that variable -- you cause **undefined behavior** and anything can happen.

---

Side note, `scanf("%s", ..)`, even if you give it an **array** of `char`, will always overflow the buffer if something longer is entered, therefore causing **undefined behavior**. You have to include a field width like

```
char str[10];
scanf("%9s", str);
```

Best is not to use `scanf()` at all. For your single character input, you can just use `getchar()` (be aware it returns an `int`). You might also want to read my [beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: thanks again for an answer.
i read of getchar but tried to get used to scanf first. But i will check out the link when learning about getchar. 
If you pass a pointer to a single char variable, - but when using %s i pass it to a char array..dont i?

Comment: See the simple example code with `%9s` above. Field width must be one less than array size because the final `0` byte of the string isn't counted in the field width...

Comment: I used `char wasd[3]; scanf("%c", &wasd[2]);`now. Why is the field width still to short when using  `char wasd[2]; scanf("%c", &wasd[1]);` ? The 0 needs only one byte..+ the byte of the value of wasd

Comment: Huh? Now I don't understand anything. Why are you now combining `%c` with an array of `char`? With `%c` there's no field width -- the field width in my example is the `9` in `%9s`.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` variable can hold only one byte of memory to hold a single character. But a string (array of characters) is different from a `char` variable as it is always ended with a null character `\0` or numeric `0`. So in `scanf` you specifically mentioned whether you are reading a character or a string so that `scanf` can add a null character at the end of a string. So you are not suppose to use a `%s` to read a value for a `char` variable